# how to input text parameter to GET api with space

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an http service to GET movies api data it works fine but if i input 2 words for example
"The Batman" it's not working because it will return null but if i only input 1 word "Batman" it works fine, im still new with query query things

if you have the answer can you please answer with my full code ? because im quite slow to understand some logic

here is my code

```
Future searchMovie(movieName) async {

Uri url = Uri.parse('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={key}&query=$movieName');

var response = await http.get(url);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['results'];
  List<SearchMovieModel> searchedMovies = [];

  for (var item in data) {
    searchedMovies.add(SearchMovieModel.fromJson(item));
  }

  return searchedMovies;
} else {
  throw Exception('Error get data');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this way.

```
  String query ='The Batman';
  await get(Uri.parse('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie').replace(
     queryParameters:  {
       'api_key' :'key',
        'query' : query    
       }
  ));
```

Comment: can you put it in my code?

Comment: yes sure just replace your api_key

Comment: thanks it works i don't know if query works like that

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer as its working for you

Comment: one more, how if the url like this ? Uri url = Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/movie/$movieId$_apiKey');

Comment: is it  baseurl/movie/movieId/api_key right  or something else ?

Comment: i mean how to put queryParameters if the url like this, since movie_id doesn't need any query 
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie /{JUST_MOVIE_ID_NO_QUERY}/recommendations?api_key={API_KEY}

Comment: you can use this way  : Uri.parse('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/$movieId/recommendations')
      .replace(queryParameters: {'api_key': 'test'})